# Meteor Iron:Route with Meteor 1.2

Tags: meteor, this, iron-router

I'm learning Meteor by following [this tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/building-a-slack-clone-in-meteor-js-part-4-channels-and-chat-rooms).

Here is my git https://github.com/nicholaschong12/meteor-slackclone

I'm getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'channel' of undefined
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Function.prototype.apply: Arguments list has wrong
> type

```
Meteor.startup(function(){
    Session.set('channel',this.params.channel);
});
```

Please help me to understand this error.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'channel' of undefined

We can see that it is trying to read a property 'channel' of an undefined object.  This object from your code is:

> this.params

Reading the [iron:router docs](http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/#route-parameters), tells us that:

> When a user goes to that url, the actual value of the parameter will be stored as a property on this.params **in your route function.**

However in the code snippet you provided:

```
Meteor.startup(function(){
  Session.set('channel',this.params.channel);
});
```

You are trying to access this.params inside a Meteor.startup callback function, not a **Router.route** function.  In this context this.params is undefined, as the error is telling you.

Change your startup code to match the tutorial:

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
  Session.set('channel', 'general');
});
```

And in your routing code you can use values from the route like this:

```
Router.route('/:channel', function () {
  Session.set('channel', this.params.channel);
  this.render('messages');
});
```

In this context this.params will return an object, including the channel property defined in the routes path.